# Is there a way to disable ReactiveHealthIndicators in Spring Boot 2 Actuator?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Using Spring Boot 2.1.2 Actuator. I have Redis in my classpath. Actuator is automatically enabling RedisReactiveHealthIndicator. I don't want that. My app is not reactive. I want RedisHealthIndicator, but the reactive one is replacing it.

Is there a way to stop auto-enabling of reactive health indicators?

Comment: I'm baffled because I find nothing in the documentation to say how to disable just the Reactive indicators.

Answer (score 8):

```
management.health.redis.enabled = false
```

Add this to your application.properties file.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: No, sorry, I don't want to disable it, I just don't want the Reactive health indicator

Comment: Is this Not the same?

Comment: No. I want RedisHealthIndicator to run, but not RedisReactiveHealthIndicator. The reactive one doesn't work correctly in my environment, but it is replacing the standard indicator in one of my apps. I can't figure out why the reactive one is running one app and the standard one in the other. I've looked at actuator source, and it appears that the Reactive ones run instead of the standard ones if Flux class is in the classpath. However, Flux is in the class path in both my apps--I tried excluding Reactor but that causes errors at startup

Comment: Please post your pom or gradle.build file.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, is there any solution for it @DennisDoubleday?

Answer (score 0):

Than try this

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={RedisReactiveHealthIndicator.class})
```

Comment: Leads to: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes:
 - org.springframework.boot.actuate.redis.RedisReactiveHealthIndicator

Comment: @DennisDoubleday - I am facing the same issue. How did you solve this one? Thanks in advance